# Right PHP framework for the job

Tags: php

I need some recommendations about which PHP framework is the right one to use for the job I want to do;

I want to create a cloud-based application that is multi-tenancy, but has one over-arching administration system that can administer any of the tenants. Each tenant will have their own database tables, in the one large database, and the administrator for that tenant can only backup/export their tables. The users/admins require fine grained authentication and permission control. It is possible for a single user to be able to log into multiple tenants if they are part of those tenants.

RDBMS envisaged either MySQL/Maria or PostgreSQL.

It is a small business application that will have reporting, CRUD, and a lot of AJAX involved.

I have looked at using a CMS, eg Drupal, or Bolt, or October, but it would appear that there is a lot of cruft that is superfluous if I go down that track. OTOH using straight Laravel or Symfony is possible, but starting from scratch, and I am unsure of how to implement the multiple-databases-within-a-database thing cleanly.